# (React) Password input fields shows one letter at a time

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, input, components

I'm working on a project that utilizes a Register page and Login page. Before I started styling, I was able to type into the fields normally. Once I started styling I've been getting the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWGHF.png

If I type a letter into the password box, it shows up under the username field. Looking at the screencap, if I then type the letter "H" I'd see that letter under the username field instead of the "g." I figured something's mislabeled and/or in the wrong location, and the only editing I did with the styling was below the `render()` part. Also, the username fields work fine.

Here's the index.js file:

```
class Register extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        username: "",
        password: "",
        clickedRegister: false
      };
      this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
      this.handleRegisterSubmit = this.handleRegisterSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(evt) {
      console.log(evt.target);
      this.setState({
        [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value
      })
    };

    handleRegisterSubmit(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      console.log('you clicked button');
      this.setState({
        clickedLogin: true
      })
    };

    render() {
      return (

      <form onSubmit={this.handleRegisterSubmit}>
        <div className="form">
          <h2 className="create-account">Create an account!</h2>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="user-label">
              <medium className="form-text">We'll never share your username with anyone else.</medium>
              <br />
            <input className="user-box"
              name="username"
              placeholder="Enter username"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
            </label>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="pass-label">
              <br />
            <input className="user-box"
              name="username"
              placeholder="Enter password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
            </label>
            <br />
            <button className="register-button">Submit</button>
          </div>

        </div>

      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You marked the 2nd input box with name username instead of password, so might be getting wrong value.

Comment: That did it! Next time I'll watch my code more carefully. Thanks.